# JS: Making two functions do the same thing

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope

Is there a way of making this shorter?

```
var scrollPos = function() {
    var bodyTopPos =
        header.style.top <
        ( document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop ) -91;
        header.setAttribute('class', bodyTopPos ? 'sticky' : '');
}();

window.onscroll = function() {
    var bodyTopPos =
        header.style.top <
        ( document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop ) -91;
        header.setAttribute('class', bodyTopPos ? 'sticky' : '');
}
```

I've tried writing the below but it seems to automatically set the header class to sticky.

```
var scrollPos = function() {
    var bodyTopPos =
        header.style.top <
        ( document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop ) -91;
        header.setAttribute('class', bodyTopPos ? 'sticky' : '');
}();

window.onscroll = scrollPos();
```

You can see my working fiddle example **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshuaWaheed/wkz6j4dy/)**

Comment: `scrollPos` wont equal anything since your IIFE is not returning anything, in both code blocks. Why are you immediately executing the functions anyway?

Comment: Because I need it to be executed if there's an anchored location within the page. If I don't have it immediately load when the page is positioned at an anchor point, the function won't happen until the user scrolls. How can I make it return what I need it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, just make it a named function, call it, and set it as the `onscroll` handler.

```
function scroll() {
    var bodyTopPos =
        header.style.top <
        ( document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop ) -91;
        header.setAttribute('class', bodyTopPos ? 'sticky' : '');
}
scroll();
window.onscroll = scroll;
```